# How do I put indexes and words together to make 1 final string/array? (Java)

Tags: java, hashmap, position

**Background to question**

I have been working on developing code that is able to read a string, compress it an send it to a new file in a compressed form. (e.g. "hello, hello" -> "hello[0, 1]) and this works great at the moment. Here is the link for anyone who wants to use it: https://pastebin.com/v6YF34mU . The next stage is being able to re-create the file using the indexes and the words.

**Question**

I currently have got this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Pattern seaPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\[(.*?)\\],");
            String compressedSea = "see[2, 4, 5],sea[0, 1, 3],";
            Matcher seaMatcher = seaPattern.matcher(compressedSea);
            while (seaMatcher.find()) {
                String seaWords = seaMatcher.group(1);
                String[] seaIndexes = seaMatcher.group(2).split(", ");
                for (String str : seaIndexes) {
                    int seaIndex = Integer.parseInt(str);
                    System.out.print(seaIndex);
                    }
```

In short. I reads the string and splits it up into to different arrays. One of the arrays contains the indexes and the other contains the words. The next stage is putting these together and creating 1 string that is able to be compressed. I am relatively new to Java so I am not completely sure how I would go about doing this.

If anyone has got any ideas on how to do this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just to clearify, you want two arrays. One array with `{"see","sea"}` and another with `{2,4,5,0,1,3}`?

Comment: What I currently have:
see[2, 4,5], sea[0, 1, 3], -> see, sea (in seaWord array) & 245013 (in seaIndex array)


What I would like it look like:
"sea sea see sea see see"

Hopefully this clarifies it!

Comment: Okay. I whish I had read your comment before posting my solution. I missunderstood what you wanted to accomplish then. I will change my solution to fit with what you are looking for.

Comment: I have added an update to my solution, that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a class for combining your word and indexes.

I have posted a suggestion below:

**Updated answer after OP clarified what he wanted to output**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Map<Integer, String> wordMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        Pattern seaPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\[(.*?)\\],");
        String compressedSea = "see[2, 4, 5],sea[0, 1, 3],";
        Matcher seaMatcher = seaPattern.matcher(compressedSea);
        while (seaMatcher.find()) {
            String word = seaMatcher.group(1);
            String[] seaIndexes= seaMatcher.group(2).split(", ");
            for(String s : seaIndexes){
                wordMap.put(Integer.valueOf(s), word);
            }
        }
//HashMap will printout ordered by the key value.
//This is because the key is an Integer
//The hashed key value is therefore the key value itself.
        System.out.println(wordMap);
    }
```

**Output**

```
{0=sea, 1=sea, 2=see, 3=sea, 4=see, 5=see}
```

**Bonus**

If you want to iterate though the HashMap, you can do the following:

```
Iterator it = wordMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
         Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
         System.out.println(pair.getValue());
    }
```

**Output**

```
sea
sea
see
sea
see
see
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking how to put two strings into one string? Or am I understanding wrong? 
If it's just adding two strings, that can be done by using the + sign.

```
String newString = string1 + string2;
```

If you're asking how to put them into a hashmap (so key-value pair), that would be:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(value, word);
```

Comment: Yeah it would be in a hashmap

Comment: So, was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly.

Create a new array with the highest index in index array.

```
String[] finalString = new Array[highestIndex];
```

now loop through your words array

```
for(String str: wordsArray){
  //grab the index of each str
    //put your str in the new array at the same indexes
    finalString [index] = str;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what does the [highestIndex] mean I do not completely understand what you are suggesting.